# Rotate and image canvas by user defined angle

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, canvas

I want to rotate an image by user defined angle which will be determined by a input slider which ranges from -90deg to 90deg. Basically the requirement is to straighten an image on canvas.

This is what i have tried using angularjs

my input slider and html :

```
Straighten: <input type="range" id="rotateImage" value="0" min="-90" max="90" step="1" ng-model="rotateAngle"/>
<div id="imageCanvas">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

my controller:

```
$scope.$watch('rotateAngle', function(newVal, oldVal) {
if (newVal) {
    rotate(newVal)
}
})

function rotate(rotAngle) {
console.log('rotate angle>> ', rotAngle);
var imageCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var gridWidth = imageCanvas.width,
    gridHeight = imageCanvas.height;
var deg = Math.PI / 180;

context.translate(gridWidth / 2, gridHeight / 2);
context.rotate(rotAngle * deg);
}
```

Also i am drawing a grid on top of the canvas for reference

```
$scope.Straighten = function() {
var imageCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    gridWidth = imageCanvas.width,
    canvasWidth = gridWidth,
    gridHeight = imageCanvas.height,
    canvasHeight = gridHeight,
    gridPadding = 1;

var gridCanvas = $('<canvas id=gridLayer></canvas>').attr({
    width: canvasWidth,
    height: canvasHeight
}).appendTo('#imageCanvas');
var context = gridCanvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
drawGridBoard(gridWidth, gridHeight, gridPadding, context);
}

function drawGridBoard(gridWidth, gridHeight, gridPadding, context) {
for (var x = 0; x <= gridWidth; x += 40) {
    context.moveTo(0.5 + x + gridPadding, gridPadding);
    context.lineTo(0.5 + x + gridPadding, gridHeight + gridPadding);
}


for (var x = 0; x <= gridHeight; x += 40) {
    context.moveTo(gridPadding, 0.5 + x + gridPadding);
    context.lineTo(gridWidth + gridPadding, 0.5 + x + gridPadding);
}

context.strokeStyle = "blue";

context.setLineDash([15, 5]);
context.stroke();
```

}

I am able to get the angle by which the image has to be rotated but the image is not getting roatated. 
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working on canvas since couple of weeks. I'm updating your rotate function. Maybe you should have to wait until the image is loaded before you draw it. Please post below code

```
function rotate(rotAngle) {
    console.log('rotate angle>> ', rotAngle);
    var canvas= document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //Clear the canvas first

    var logoImg = new Image(); // Create instance of the Image class
    logoImg.src = item.image; // Tell the Image's relative url

    var gridWidth = canvas.width,
    var gridHeight = canvas.height;
    var deg = Math.PI / 180;


    logoImg.onload = function () {

                context.save();
                context.translate(gridWidth / 2, gridHeight / 2);

                context.rotate(rotAngle * Math.PI / 180);

                context.drawImage(logoImg, -(gridWidth / 2), -(gridHeight / 2));

                context.restore();
            };

}
```

Above code worked for me.

Comment: Thank you so much :) it worked perfectly. But my only probelm now is. the extra spaces we get when roatating. how can i fill that by zooming on the image to fill the space and also be able to pan the image?

Comment: If you see my answer is good enough, please don't forget to upvote. For your next query will you please create a fiddle so I can see myself ?